# Xcode command line tool - how to run in terminal?

Tags: xcode, command-line

When you create a Command Line Tool project in Xcode you get this, in main.m:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        // insert code here...
        NSLog(@"Hello, World!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I can run this from Xcode. But I want to compile it so that I can run it from Terminal. What are the steps?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming your executable is named "my_program", and it's in the "/foo/bar/Debug" directory:

```
cd /foo/bar
./my_program
```

If you aren't sure how to find the program file itself, you can right-click it (i.e.: the "product") and "Show in Finder" as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Note that the executable is in a completely separate location to the source code. Something like `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloWorld-gnrlmuhyaotljugurctzowgqmkfy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/HelloWorld.app.`

Answer (score 10):

You can have the terminal launch everytime you run the application through editing the scheme. I believe this became available from Xcode 8.0.

1. Access `Edit Scheme`

   [image: Edit Scheme]
2. Switch `Console` from `Use Xcode` to `Use Terminal`

   [image: Console]

Comment: This feature seem to have disapeared from Xcode (8.2.1), any tips on how to get it back?

Comment: Still don't have it, and it's another project :p But still iOS project. Must be restricted to OSX ones imho

Answer (score 6):

In Xcode 9 you can try the following (works for me in June 2018):

1. instead of 'edit scheme' click 'new scheme', give it a name and save
2. now choose that new scheme you've just created and click 'edit
   scheme'
3. go to the 'Info' tab and in a menu 'Executable' choose
   'Other...'
4. in file window go to search input field and type
   'terminal' and click on its icon when you find it. Now you should see 'Terminal.app' in 'Executable' field
5. go to the 'Arguments' tab, click on + and copy and paste this line there: `${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FULL_PRODUCT_NAME}`
6. click 'close' and run your program with your new scheme selected

Normally Xcode will open terminal for you. If not, you may also turn off any debug related fields in the 'Info' tab. Hope this helps!

Full tutorial here: 
https://www.raywenderlich.com/163134/command-line-programs-macos-tutorial-2

Comment: I needed to remove spaces from my project name and folder to make this work.

Comment: The downside of this approach is debugging.  Citation to the RW author: `you can't debug your app in Xcode this way because now the executable that Xcode launches during a run is Terminal. `