# xcode change the console output to terminal 9.1

Tags: c++, xcode

Hey guys i'm learning about algorithms at the moment and I have written the Lee algorithm.

What I'm trying to do now is highlight the shortest path it finds in red text in the console.

I found this thread which explains what it is I'm trying to do however the option is no longer there in xcode 9.1

The answer: [Output bold text to console in C (on Mac - Xcode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40752107/output-bold-text-to-console-in-c-on-mac-xcode)

When I go through `edit scheme > options > run` the tickbox is not there, any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Solution:

1. instead of 'edit scheme' click 'new scheme', give it a name and save
2. now choose that new scheme you've just created and click 'edit
   scheme'
3. go to the 'Info' tab and in a menu 'Executable' choose
   'Other...'
4. in file window go to search input field and type
   'terminal' and click on its icon when you find it. Now you should see 'Terminal.app' in 'Executable' field
5. go to the 'Arguments' tab, click on + and copy and paste this line there: `${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FULL_PRODUCT_NAME}`
6. click 'close' and run your program with your new scheme selected

Normally Xcode will open terminal for you. If not, you may also turn off any debug related fields in the 'Info' tab. Hope this helps!

Full tutorial here: 
https://www.raywenderlich.com/163134/command-line-programs-macos-tutorial-2

Comment: This is a great answer, if you want to run your app.  If you want to debug it in Terminal, things get harder.

Answer (score 0):

when in `edit scheme > options > run`, by default it would be under `info` tab. That checkbox will be available under `option` section [image]